# swift cannot update FCM token

Tags: swift, firebase, google-cloud-platform, firebase-cloud-messaging

i'm trying to update my FCM token if a new token is available. Unfortunately i'm getting this error:

> found nil while implicitly unwrapping an Optional value

Here is my code:

```
func messaging(_ messaging: Messaging, didReceiveRegistrationToken fcmToken: String) {
    print("Firebase registration token: \(fcmToken)")

    let dataDict:[String: String] = ["token": fcmToken]
    NotificationCenter.default.post(name: Notification.Name("FCMToken"), object: nil, userInfo: dataDict)
    if Auth.auth().currentUser == nil{

    }else{
        if Auth.auth().currentUser!.uid == nil{

        }else{
            db.collection("Users").document(Auth.auth().currentUser!.uid).setData([ "fcm": fcmToken ], merge: true)

        }
    }
```

I think its because my uid is nil but i'm checking it before

Comment: which line ..............

Answer (score 0):

The `currentUser` is optional but the `uid` on a `currentUser` is not. Try safely unwrapping the `currentUser` like so:

```
func messaging(_ messaging: Messaging, didReceiveRegistrationToken fcmToken: String) {
    print("Firebase registration token: \(fcmToken)")

    let dataDict:[String: String] = ["token": fcmToken]
    NotificationCenter.default.post(name: Notification.Name("FCMToken"), object: nil, userInfo: dataDict)

    if let currentUser = Auth.auth().currentUser {
        db.collection("Users").document(currentUser.uid).setData([ "fcm": fcmToken ], merge: true)
    }
}
```